# Curl PHP Session Out

Tags: php, curl

I got problem which is session out. The problem is I can connect to website with login panel, but after all when I click other links onto website , it was like as if i did not log in the website. So, how can i code something to keep online to website? What should i do for this?

---

`<?php


function login ($url,$information){

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $information);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    }

    login("http://www.na.edu/online/login/index.php","username=user&password=blablabla");

?>`

Comment: Did the request create the `cookie.txt` file?

Comment: Actually, I created myself. Because request did not create it. After i logged in the website. I always checked the cookie file but there was nothing inside of it. I dont know why. I cant pull the cookie from website.

Comment: Be sure u've set the right (chmod) permissions so that PHP is able to write to that file :)

Comment: i succeed to wrote that file. But now same error again. It seems like even if i log in the website, when i click to something on the webpage , it automatically logs out.

Comment: U have to set the cookie jar for every request u do

Comment: could you show me an example on my code if it is possible?

Comment: Just wrap your curl post in a function and post accordingly see [this](http://www.darkbee.be/cookiejar/curl.php) (source is at the bottom)